# 3 numbers the same from a random numbers list between 1-9

Tags: javascript

If I have a array that gives me 9 random numbers, from a list of 9 numbers, how do I make sure that it can only duplicate 3 of the same numbers?
for example if my random numbers array is [4,3,4,4,7,8,8,8,9].
I need there to only be one trio of numbers in any one array not two like seen above.

Comment: can you share the code to produce these random numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to replace `randomNum` with whatever it is you are using to store the random numbers being added to the array, but try this:

```
var arrayOfRandomNums = [];

function maxInstancesInArray(arr, val) {
    var hits = [];
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] === val)
            indexes.push(i);
    return indexes.length > 2;
}

if(!maxInstancesInArray(arrayOfRandomNums, randomNum) {
    arrayOfRandomNums.push(randomNum);
}
```

The function will return true if there are 3 or more instances of the incoming number already in the array, so you can use that to define whether or not you push the next one to the array.

Answer (score 0):

i've made a jsFiddle that can help. the idea is that instead of trying to get rundom numbers everytime and check, to have the list of available numbers in an array and random the index of this array.

https://jsfiddle.net/m8ohmxmb/

```
  function randNumber(maxRange,maxOccurrencies, resultArrayLenght) {
     var num = [];
     var occ = [];
     var result = [];
     var randElem;

     for (var i = 0; i < maxRange; i++) {
        num.push(i + 1);
        occ.push(0);
     }

     for(i = 0; i < resultArrayLenght; i++) {
         randElem = Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length);  
         occ[randElem] = occ[randElem] + 1;
         result.push(num[randElem]);
         if(occ[randElem] === maxOccurrencies) {
             occ.splice(randElem,1);
             num.splice(randElem,1);
         }
     }
     return result;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I have fixed it now, I just used indexOf and cycled through my array until it matched the indexOf element.

Comment: for example: inside a do loopuse a if statementlike this:    if randomNumber==1 && this.array.indexOf(1) !=-1 This will then change the variable set at the beginning of the do loop to true

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight forward approach with a temporary object for keeping the insertet values and their count.

```js
function push(n) {
    if (count.full && count[n] === 2) {
        alert('can not insert ' + n);
        return;
    }
    array.push(n);
    count[n] = (count[n] || 0) + 1;
    if (count[n] === 3) {
        count.full = true;
    }
}

var array = [],
    count = {};

[4, 3, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9].forEach(push);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```